# Can't see home folder space

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS as shown [image: here].

But after installation it doesn't show free space of my home folder which is supposed to be 88.5 GB.

```
emre@toshiba:~$ du -h
126M .

emre@toshiba:~$ df -h /home
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        81G  245M   77G   1% /home
```

Disk Usage Analyzer even [image: doesn't show] it.

Also here is my gparted results.

[image]

Where is my free space?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `df -h /home`

Comment: @user68186 Thank you but it show only ~120MB not GB.

Comment: @vidarlo Thank you. I edited the question as you said.

Comment: Install **gparted** from **Ubuntu Software**. Run gparted. Add a screenshot of gparted in the question.

Comment: @user68186 Thank you for you attention again. I did as you said.

Comment: Both gparted and `df -h /home` shows your free space exactly where they should be in your `/home` partition.

Comment: But why du -h shows only something mb instead of gb. I always use du -h. Normally I use du -h to see how big is a folder. I'm confused. df -h only shows whole disk. Consider a folder contains two low reso. pictures. du -h shows perfectly their size. But df doesn't show.

Comment: `du` shows how much space some files occupy, `df` shows the file system/disk space usage (total capacity, used space, available space). `du -sh /home` and `df -h /home` should show similar values for the used space, if /home is a separate partition (as it is in your case). Check the manual pages (`man du` and `man df`) for more information. I personally remember which command is which as "d**u** shows how much space my files **u**se, d**f** tells me the **f**ree and **f**ull space of my disk."

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks. After reading your comment I'm enlightened now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do have the free space (77GB Available from the df command and 80GB Unused from the gparted tool).

The reason it is not 88.5GB could be either filesystem related (the filesystem uses some of that space for itself) or the home folder is already starting to fill (some programs store their files in the home directory for cache, thumbnails, etc.)